# Vim syntax folding with perl

Tags: perl, vim, folding

I use vim at work for developing pretty sizable perl code, and I got stuck while trying to learn how to use folds properly.

(Note: I'm still relatively new to Vim - switched over from gedit about half a year ago, but I'm still learning the new powerful things everyday!)

This is my portion of .vimrc related to folding

```
" mouse is on
set mouse=a
" folding
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldlevelstart=1
let perl_fold=1
let sh_fold_enabled=1
let perl_extended_vars=1
let perl_sync_dist=250
```

So this thing is good in that it folds all the code, and I can freely open / close folds with simply pressing z-a. But it's also bad in that *everything* is folded when I open a file.

Is there a way to have the file *not* be folded when I open the file, but still allow me to open/close blocks of code based on perl syntax with z-a? (or some other keystroke)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "fold level" is the depth of the fold:

```
1
  2
    3
```

The line that you put in your `~/.vimrc`,

```
set foldlevelstart=1
```

tells vim fo close every fold up to level 1 by default.

Set it to an impossibly high value to open all folds by default:

```
set foldlevelstart=999
```

Note that you can also try a low level like `2` or `3` which may have interesting results depending on your coding style.

See `:h foldlevelstart`.

Comment: See also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file for some fancier methods for getting just the right level to open all the folds when you start editing.